# Convert Angular Firestore Collection Data to Array

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Iam trying to insert Angular Firestore query response data into JSPDF

- No output of data array in PDF table rows:

My Code:

```
export interface Board{  
  boardTitle:string;  
  boardDescription:string;  
}  

ngOnInit(){

    const BoardsArray = [];
    firebase.firestore().collection('boards').get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        BoardsArray.push(doc.data());
      });
    });

    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const col = ['boardTitle', 'boardDescription'];
    const rows = [];

    BoardsArray.forEach(element => {
    const temp = [element.boardTitle, element.boardDescription];
    rows.push(temp);
    });

    doc.autoTable(col, rows);
    doc.save('Test.pdf');
  }
```

** Console output for firestore data response:
[image]

** But With this Sample Data iam getting Fine Output:

```
ngOnInit(){

    const BoardsArray: Board[] = [  
      {boardTitle: 'Title1', boardDescription: 'Hello'},  
      {boardTitle: 'Title2', boardDescription: 'Hello2'},  
      {boardTitle: 'Title3', boardDescription: 'Hello3'}  
   ];  

    const doc = new jsPDF();
    const col = ['boardTitle', 'boardDescription'];
    const rows = [];

    BoardsArray.forEach(element => {
    const temp = [element.boardTitle, element.boardDescription];
    rows.push(temp);
    });

    doc.autoTable(col, rows);
    doc.save('Test.pdf');

  }
```

Please Check if iam missing something! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably Promise, getting collection data have some delay, so your execution is faster then your data is received. I recommend you move your logic into async function where you can use await before getting data from collection. Or move your pdf creation into the promise resolve function after your push function.

8 months later.. hope it helped :)